# Routing URLs are not working after install Godaddy SSL Certificate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I had developed ASP.NET MVC Website & hosted It on **GoDaddy** shared windows hosting, it was working fine until I purchased a managed SSL Certificates,  only homepage is working any other URL return error message:

> "The resource cannot be found."

Comment: What makes you think your SSL cert actually has anything to do with the routes? Why did you tag asp.net-mvc-4 and asp.net-mvc-3? Surely you're not using both of those, and likely neither of those?

Comment: because I deployed the website before installing SSL & it was working fine for all routes.

Comment: And if you remove the cert, it all starts working again?

Comment: actually It had been added by Godaddy Technical team because I bought a Managed SSL Certificate which means they responsible for install it ,I think yes becuase the website was working well before it had been installed.

Comment: I doubt it. Most likely something else has changed. Have you tried republishing your site? Adding logging? Monitoring your browser to see if it's being redirected around?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The SSL Certificate won't make changes to your API or routing or anything except for enabling secure communication.